# Deleting many to many relationship fails after binding form in symfony 2.3.1

Tags: forms, binding, symfony-2.3

I have entities in which employee has many skills.So there is many-to-many relationship between employee and skill entities. Now lets say I have employee form which has skill collection.skill is added dynamically in twig through ajax.

My partial controller code is:

```
echo "b4 count ".count($employee->getemployeeSkills());
if(isset($_POST['data'])){                      
    $employeeForm->bind($request);
    echo "after count ".count($employee->getemployeeSkills());
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    if ($employeeForm->isValid()) {
       $em->persist($employee); 
       $em->flush;
```

Now "`b4 count is 3`" and `after count is 2` when I deleted 1 skill from 3 skills of employee.
But after flush record won't delete from DB. It shows that only in `$employeeForm` it gets deleted.